# Create Map with several keys in java

Tags: java

I would like to create Map like this:

```
Map<int, String, String> map = new ArrayList<>();

map.(100, "SystemError", "General error");
```

Can you recommend some proper Java collection that can store multiple values like the above example?

Comment: `Map<Integer,List<String>>`?

Comment: It's not very useful in my case.

Comment: You can also construct a sort of `Pair` with two arbitrary objects in it. `Map<Integer, Pair<String, String>>`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Could you explain your problem. Maybe a map isn't even the best solution. What kind of keys do you have and what kind of values? Are those strings "System error" and "General error" also supposed to be keys or are they values?

Comment: I want to store a collection with system errors. I need 3 values.

Comment: So your key would always be an int but you want multiple (String) values related to one key?

Comment: Yes, but I need also to get key 3 from key 2.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Could you update your answer and explain your problem and what you're trying to achieve with more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<Integer, Collection<String>> errorMap = new HashMap<>();
errorMap.put(100, Arrays.asList("System error", "General error"));

Collection<String> errorNames = errorMap.get(100);
```

Comment: Note that `Arrays.asList` accepts varargs, so `new String[] {"System error", "General error"}` could be replaced with simply `Arrays.asList("System error", "General error")`.

Answer (score 2):

It would be far better to create your own class

```
class Error {
    private int id;
    private String logString;
    private String description;
    // plus getters and setters
}
```

and then have a `List<Error>`. If you need a map, you can create it via

```
Map<Integer, List<Error>> errorMap = errorList.stream().collect(groupingBy(Error::getId));
```

Comment: Is there a solution without Java Object?

Comment: @PeterPenzov you could just use `Map<Integer, List<String>` then you don't have to create a class

Comment: Or use `Map.Entry<String,String>` to hold them. Then you get a `Map<String, Entry<String, String>>`

Comment: But custom class is really the best. Gives you nice named getters.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to Apache Commons [MultiValuedMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html). It can store multiple values for a single key.

```
MultiValuedMap<Integer, String> map = new MultiValuedHashMap<>();
map.put(1, "A");
map.put(1, "B");
map.put(1, "C");
Collection<String> coll = map.get(1);
```

`coll` will contain values "A", "B" and "C".

Also Java EE defines his own alternative: [MultivaluedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html), which seems to be very similar to Apache's one (almost identical as I see).

Comment: Is there any solution with core Java?

Comment: Java EE has a similar data structure. I will update my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use-case, there are three possible answers:

- If your example was using just a single key and multiple value (which I think that is the case from the example you provided), then you can use something out of the box such as [Apache MultiValueMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiValueMap.html) which is basically a decorator for the Java Map with an ArrayList as the value.
- If you need flexibility to either use multiple keys or multiple values, then you can use the [Eclipse Collections Tuple](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/tuple/Tuples.html) to pair the multiple elements together and insert them as a single key/value.
- If you do not need to add any external library in your code, then you can do what Apache Commons does by delegating or decorating a Map with an ArrayList for holding the multiple keys/values.

Comment: Is there any solution with core Java?